# Use ReplaceAll in find/replace, but drop the source format

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need some help. I have some code which copies a filtered range from an Excel worksheet and pastes it in Word in various locations, replacing a specific word. The issue is when I don't use `wdReplaceAll` it seems to paste the value using the destination format (one time). However when I use ReplaceAll the source Excel format is included, which I don't want. Now I have tried insisting on a specific format with ReplaceAll which did not work but frankly I would prefer destination format. Can anyone help?:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "What"
    .Replacement.Text = "^c"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
```

Comment: You have the .Format option set to True so you are instructing the Find/Replace to copy formatting. Try setting it to false.

Comment: Yeah sorry this was false earlier and I changed it to True as I was experimenting with defining a format, but this was ignored as well by the code. thanks

Comment: Look in File/Options/Advanced, at the "Cut, copy and paste" section. You should see "Pasting from other program" in the list of options. Try "Keep text only" as the setting. If that doesn't help, you may also want to look at the "User smart cut and paste" settings. If all else fails, you'll need to do each Find/Replace separately, in a loop.

Comment: There is nothing about your code to indicate how Excel is involved in either a single replacement or via Find/Replace with Replace All. That said, if you've copied some formatted content to the clipboard and you're using that with the ^c replace expression, as your macro suggests, then it's the formatted content that will be output, regardless of whether you have .Format = True. For some generalised code to use an Excel workbook as the data source for a series of Find/Replace actions, see: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/22669-created-vba-find-replace-body-header-footer.html#post70404

Comment: Macropod  Thanks for your help. The VBA word script opens a spreadsheet, filters based on a primary key and copies certain cell and pastes in word document in several places from clipboard.

Comment: Cindy Meister Thanks for the response. I tried both under settings and this did not help. I was thinking of doing a loop but not my strong suit. can you get me started? I have updated the code above which works fine as it only does one instance of replace and obeys the destination formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to define a range object prior to executing your code such as:

```
set rng = Selection.FormattedText
```

Then after doing a ReplaceAll, select the range and apply any style you want such as:

```
rng.Select
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
```